# Mongoose cascade middleware, multiple levels

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get thecascading 'remove' middleware working on mongoose.

I have a database were i have:

```
'modules' -> 'modulesInst' -> 'assignments' -> 'studentAssignments'
```

So when modules delete, it cascades 'modulesInst', and when modulesInst deletes it deletes 'assignments' related, and then the same with 'student assignments'.

Problem is I can only get it working at one level.

**Top level schema and 'remove' middleware (module)**

```
var modulesSchema = new Schema (
        {
            _id: Number,
            moduleName: String,
            moduleLeader: String
        }
    );

modulesSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
    modulesInst.remove({modID: this._id}).exec();
    next();
});
```

**Second level schema and 'remove' middleare (moduleInst) [where the middleware stops cascading]**

```
var modulesInstSchema = new Schema (
    {
        year: Number,
        semester: String,
        modID: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Module' }],
    }
);

modulesInstSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    assignment.remove({modInsID: this._id}).exec();
    next();
});
```

**third level of schema and 'remove' middleware (assignment) [the middleware doesn't trigger aswell]**

```
var assignmentSchema = new Schema (
    {
        code: String,
        assignName: String,
        modInsID: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'ModuleInst' }],
    }
);

assignmentSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    studentAssign.remove({assID: this._id}).exec();
    next();
});
```

Is there a simple trick I am missing to keep cascading? As the documentation is not clear and cannot find examples.

Answer (score 2):

`Model.remove()` method doesn't fire the middleware. From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html):

> Note: There is no query hook for remove(), only for documents. If you set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call myDoc.remove(), not when you call MyModel.remove().

That said, you must do this at the document level, for example (using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)'s promises):

```js
modulesInt
  .find({ modID: this._id })
  .then((modules) => Promise.each(modules, (module) => module.remove()))
  .then(next)
  .catch(next)
```

Comment: This actually helped me to go in the right direction, and after some tinkering I got it to work. Had to use individual promise returns in the loop however. I really wish this was easier lol.